# How are exploding numbers in a forward pass of a CNN combated?

Tags: machine-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, relu

Take AlexNet for example:

[image: combined gpu stream of alexnet]

In this case, only the activation function ReLU is used. Due to the fact ReLU cannot be saturated, it instead explodes, like in the following example:

Say I have a weight matrix of `[-1,-2,3,4]` and inputs of `[ReLU(4), ReLU(5), ReLU(-2), Relu(-3)]`. The resultant matrix from these will have large numbers for the inputs of `ReLU(4)` and `ReLU(5)`, and 0 for `ReLU(-2)` and `ReLU(-3)`. If there are even just a few more layers, the numbers are quick to either explode or be 0.

How is this typically combated? How do you keep these numbers towards 0? I understand you can take subtract the mean at the end of each layer, but for a layer that is already in the millions, subtracting the mean will still result in thousands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most effective way to prevent both the forward and backward propagation of *exploding* is keeping the weights in a small range. The main way this is accomplished is through their **initialization**.

For example in the case of [He initialization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.01852.pdf), the authors show (given some assumptions) that the variance of the output of the final layer $L$ of the network is:

$$
Var[y_L] = Var[y_1] \left( \prod_{i=2}^L{\frac{1}{2} \, n_l \, Var[w_l]} \right)
$$

where $n_l$ and $w_l$ are the number of connections and weights of layer $l$. In order to keep the outputs from exploding the product above should not exponentially magnify its inputs. In order to do this the authors elect to initialize the weights so that:

$$
\frac{1}{2} \, n_l \, Var[w_l] = 1
$$

Now this is helps keeping the outputs from exploding. They then go and prove that the same strategy helps preventing the gradients from exploding.

Another similar strategy is the so-called [Glorot (or Xavier) Initialization](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v9/glorot10a/glorot10a.pdf).
These techniques are **extremely effective** in helping the models converge!

Comment: I had thought maybe this could be a solution, but assumed there was a way of applying this such that it was independent of the number of weights/layers. Thankyou for linking the paper, I'll give it a read when I get the time